# Chromium browser: how to move BubbleDialogDelegateView widget without flickering?

Tags: c++, webview, chromium

I have a popup dialog based on views::BubbleDialogDelegateView ( similar to ProfileChooserView ).

```
class WebViewPopup : public views::BubbleDialogDelegateView,
                       public ExtensionViewViews::Container,
                       public content::NotificationObserver,
                       public TabStripModelObserver,
                       public content::DevToolsAgentHostObserver,
                       public zoom::ZoomObserver,
                       public FullscreenObserver
{
....
static void ShowPopup(views::Button* anchor_button,
                        Browser* browser) {
  auto* popup =
      new WebViewPopup(anchor_button, browser);
  views::BubbleDialogDelegateView::CreateBubble(popup);
}
....
}
```

And I need to move it from left to right (animate) when window appears. Similar to Opera easy setup bar.
Is there a cross-platform way to move or animate a widget without flickering?

If I imitate animation using timer and change widget size step-by-step, it flickers

```
void WebViewPopup::SetPaneWidth(int w)
{
  views::Widget* this_widget = this->GetWidget();
  gfx::Rect bounds(); //calculate new widget size
  this_widget->SetBounds(bounds); // flickers!
}
```

I've found window animation in chromium\src\ui\wm\core\window_animations.cc and it works ok, but it uses Aura and only available on Windows.

So, main question again: Is there a cross-platform way to move or animate a widget without flickering?